# Highlighting issue for Search Text - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, highlight

I have a React Native App and i have a Search Bar and a FlatList. When I Search something in the SearchBar the text has to be highlighted in the list.

Single string search works fine:

But now when I type "visit hour" neither visit or hour gets highlighted

I am using a function for highlighting the text. SearchBar value is stored as this.state.value and I am passing it as props.
The logic I am using inside renderItem of Flatlist is as below

```
getHighlightedText = text => {
  const {value} = this.props
  const parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${value})`, 'gim'));
  console.log('split:', parts);
  return (
    <Text>{parts.map(part => (
      part.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()) ?
        <Text style = {{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>{part}</Text> :
        part)}
    </Text>
  );
}
return <Text>{getHighlightedText(Desc)}</Text>;
```

This works fine when I search one word.
For Example if my flat list has 2 items - "My Dog" and "Her Cat". 
If my Search Text is "Dog" then Dog is highlighted in red. 
But if I Search "M Dog" or "M D" then nothing gets Highlighted. It has to highlight characters rather than words. Please help me fix the code!!!!!

**Updated my code**

So I will be splitting the search value and then try to highlight for each search text. if I enter "visit hour" its split into "visit" and "hour".
For some reason the loop executed only for "visit" and not "hour". Some mistake in my code. I have only added a for loop. Please help!!! :

```
getHighlightedText = text => {
  // search value is split and stored in val array. "list" and "hour"
  const val = value.split(' ');

  // below my item Description is split based on my search
  // terms "visit" n "hour" and then stored in vals array
  const vals = val.map(valu => {.
    var regex = new RegExp(`(${valu})`, 'gim');
    return text.split(regex);
  })

  // vals is merged into 1 array
  const merged = [].concat.apply([], vals);

  // below I am looping for each of my search text 1st
  // "visit" then "hour"         
  for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    const l = val[i];

    return (
      <Text>{merged.map(part => (
          part.toLowerCase() === l.toLowerCase()) ?
          <Text style = {{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>{part}</Text> :
          part
        )}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

// using my getHighlightedText in my renderItem
return <Text>{getHighlightedText(Desc)}</Text>;
```

Loop is getting terminated because of the return statement.
"visit" is highlighted but "hour" is not as the loop never reached "hour".

Help please!!!

Comment: What is `const parts = text.split(regex);` doing?
And you return twice? Is it work? Or render different text below the screen?

Comment: It is splitting my Desc of each item that is "Test Message - visiting hour". It's splitting based on my search value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `string.includes(substring)` insteads `===` .

Because using `===` represent the same value. But includes just need "contains".

This may solved your problem, take it a try. :)

```js
return (
  <Text>{parts.map(part => (value.toLowerCase().includes(part.toLowerCase())) ?
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>{part}</Text> : part)}
  </Text>);
}
```

**UPD1:**

If your want to achieve similar effect, I would suggest you to split the search string by `.split(" ");` to array, and map each string in array to highlight

**UPD2:**

You don't have to using for loop! Just add it in to your condition something like:

```js
{parts.map(part =>
  (part[0].toLowerCase() === valu.toLowerCase()
  || part[1].toLowerCase() === valu.toLowerCase()) // change to your parameter
```

Comment: tried that and it did not work. Guess the issue is with my RegExp. tried \s \\s too. Updated my question with images of my search bar.

Comment: Guess I have to split my search value inside the getHighlightedText function and then highlight it individually. If my search value is "Visit hour" I should split it into "List" and "hour" and then pass this individual values. Do you think it will work??

Comment: I have seen your new question, but it should be not highlight! According to your logic, it should highlight most of the word if I search:"our ing age".  It really weird.  I have update the answer to suggest.

Comment: It should be highlight like searching : "visiting-hour" or "visiting, hour"

Comment: yes I have added a For loop (see my updated question) some issue with it.

Comment: You don't need to add a for loop, I have update my answer.

Comment: no I cannot do that. As we won't know how the user might enter the text. They can enter like "vis hou Test".  Need something dynamic.

Comment: You can use [nested map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615559/react-map-over-nested-array-of-objects)